# Linux. Заблокировать доступ к директории и её файлам

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Как в 'Linux' закрыть доступ к директории без возможности открытия и просмотра её файлов через файловые менеджеры и терминалы?

Comment: chmod не помог?

Comment: @pavel, chmod работает, но я могу заходить в папки и видеть файлы, но не редактировать их.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user@PC:~$ sudo mkdir testdir
user@PC:~$ sudo chmod 700 testdir/

user@PC:~$ cd testdir/
bash: cd: testdir/: Permission denied
user@PC:~$ ls testdir/
ls: cannot open directory testdir/: Permission denied
```

Или вместо рута создать от другого пользователя директорию. Ключевой момент - кто владелец данной директории.

P.S. [забавности](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/10685756)